# How can I create a Windows Performance Counter with Delphi?

Tags: performance, delphi, winapi, wmi, monitoring

I developed an application that needs to be monitored.  Our monitoring site manager wants my app generates some performance parameters through "windows performance monitor".

Then he can monitor them in windows and "ApplicationManger" product of "ManageEngine" company through WMI.

I am searching for Delphi implementation to register/create windows performance counter and set their values.

Comment: Are you sure you want to open the door to the remote WMI ? I would personaly consider different way. But anyway, your question is quite unclear to me. You're looking for Delphi implementation of what ? Could you be more specific on what params you want to register/create and which values do you want to set ? Or, are you just looking for some ready made solution of a remote performance monitor ?

Comment: Thanks TLama, My site use "ApplicationManger" product of "ManageEngine" company to monitor applications. That app have a feature named "Windows Performance Counters Monitoring" uses WMI. I want my Delphi application creates/register some counters and fill them that usable in windows's "performance monitor" and mentioned application also. To do that I need a way directly or by a componenet to do that. Thanks

Comment: Have a look to the WMI Delphi Code Creator. http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/wmi-delphi-code-creator/

Comment: You are looking for an API function to create a custom Windows Performance Counters for your application? Added winapi tag.

Comment: @Polymorphin, that should be an answer.

Comment: You did read the documentation right? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373083.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create (register) and consume  [performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373083%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are a very very wide topic. You can create performance counters from **Native Code** (C++´or Delphi) for you own App using these alternatives

---

Using a  Performance Extension DLL.

- [Creating a Performance Extension DLL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371925%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Adding Performance Counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa371643%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

---

Providing Counter Data Using Version 2.0 (Windows Vista +)

- [Providing Counter Data Using Version 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965334%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

---

Creating a WMI Performance Provider creating a COM Server that implements the IWbemHiPerfProvider interface.

- [IWbemHiPerfProvider interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa391758%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- [Developing WMI Hi-Perf Provider using C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11969/Developing-WMI-Hi-Perf-Provider-using-C)

---

I'm not aware of any Delphi sample project for create performance counters. In the past I used .Net and Delphi to create some performance counters for my customers, unfortunately I can't share this code. But because you mention the WMI in your questions  I will recommend you read the [MSDN documentation about the performance counters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371643%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), then check this article [Developing WMI Hi-Perf Provider using C++](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11969/Developing-WMI-Hi-Perf-Provider-using-C), and finally translate the code of the article to Delphi and if you have any **specific** issue you can come back and a ask a new question.

Comment: You can find an example [here](http://tondrej.blogspot.com/2004/09/perfmon-ready.html).